# Openssl, RSA: why public key is required for private_decrypt?

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa

I use an Openssl library to provide RSA encryption-decryption for my app. And this is what I found:

```
 int RSA_private_decrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from,
                         unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
```

*RSA_private_decrypt() decrypts the **flen** bytes at **from** using the private key **rsa** and stores the plaintext in **to**.* (From the docs, https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_private_decrypt.html)

To setup RSA structure I use the following method:

```
int RSA_set0_key(RSA *r, BIGNUM *n, BIGNUM *e, BIGNUM *d);
```

*The **n**, **e** and **d** parameter values can be set by calling RSA_set0_key() and passing the new values for **n**, **e** and **d** as parameters to the function. The values **n** and **e** must be non-NULL the first time this function is called on a given RSA object. The value **d** may be NULL.*  (From the docs, https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_set0_key.html)

So, when I use the stuff above for **decryption** as described, everything works fine. I set `RSA` struct with `n`, `e` and `d`, then pass `RSA` struct to `private_decrypt()` with other parameters and get correct result.

But if I do **not** set `e` to `RSA` struct (or set it with random value to avoid not-null constraint), `private_decrypt()` returns wrong decryption result (all zeroes typically).

So, why does e required for private decryption? As far as RSA algorithm works, it should be enough to have n, d and cipher_text to provide correct result, isn't it?

Comment: Perhaps it uses e, d, and n to calculate other values, e.g. the CRT values. You can always look at the source code to see.

Comment: Another option is that it uses to validate the result by performing the opposite operation. That's quite common for verification, less so for decryption though. Good question though - unfortunately for OpenSSL I don't know the answer.

Comment: @JamesKPolk as far as I understand, to calculate CRT (Chinese Remainder Theorem, right?) you also need p and q values at least. But I do not pass p and q to RSA neither in first (working) or second (non-working) case

Comment: you can calculate p and q from e, d, and n.

Comment: @PVoLan Yep, created such code for Java. Also including factoring the RSA public key by the way. In the end you just need the modulus and private exponent (assuming the public exponent is relatively small) or just p and q of course.